# Parsing file list for import into mySQL

Tags: regex, bash

I need to parse filenames so that I can import them into mySQL.  The files are named like this:

```
Test 000.txt
My Test 002.txt
The-Test.txt
000Test 222.txt
Test 1.txt
Test 04.txt
```

I would like to parse them so I can import the text part and numeric part separately.

```
Name          Version
----          -------
Test          0
My Test       2
The-Test  
000Test       222
Test          1
Test          4
```

The version part will always be the numbers before the file extension.

Comment: Are the filenames in a list or do you need to scan a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while read f; do
  prefix=`echo $f | sed -e 's/ *[0-9]*.txt//'`
  number=`echo $f | sed -e "s/$prefix *//" -e s/.txt//`
  echo $prefix/$number
done << eof
  Test 000.txt
  My Test 002.txt
  The-Test.txt
  000Test 222.txt
  Test 1.txt
  Test 04.txt
eof
```